# Es necesario dividir una tabla Mysql en dos solo para evitar que tenga muchas columnas? (Normalizacion de Base de datos)

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Actualmente tengo un sistema de captura de pedidos, con una tabla con los datos del cliente y una con el catalogo de productos, actualmente hay clientes con precios especiales ( diferentes al catalogo normal) por lo cual se decidió asignarle una categoria a cada cliente segun los precios que se le ofrezcan y asimismo tener un catalogo diferente por cada categoria.

El problema aqui es que de 2 columnas de precio que tenia en el catalogo (precio de compra y precio de venta) pasaria a tener 12 columnas de precio distintas (Pues se crearon 11 categorias de clientes cada una con sus precios particulares mas la columna del precio de compra), y considerando que actualmente mi tabla de catalogo ya cuenta con 12 columnas , al final con este cambio pasaria a tener una tabla con 22 Columnas.

La pregunta es: Necesito dividir mi tabla de 22 Columnas en dos? una con la informacion general de cada producto y una solo con los precios? o puedo mantener mi tabla con muchas columnas pero que al final me facilita hacer la actualizacion de la informacion de todos los productos en general pues hasta la tercera forma normal no veo ningun problema en esto

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si no entendí mal el modelo, deberias tener otra tabla llamada cliente_categorias, en la cual tendrías id_cliente  id_categoria.De esa manera, si en un futuro deciden agregar mas categorias, seria una tupla mas en esa categoria, entonces quedaría:
id_cliente   id_categoria
1             1
1             2
.
.
1             12
2             1
2             2

Saludos

Comment: Claro, eso tambien, pero mi duda principal es si hay un problema que mi tabla de catalogo tenga 12 columnas mas ( por los precios que tiene cada categoria)

Comment: No hay problema por eso, se suele tener tablas con muchas columnas, yo lo haría como te comente, en otra tabla de uno a muchos... pero si resuelve tu problema está bien, quizá tengas problemas en el futuro con ese diseño.